# Carthage Parse error

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, carthage

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i have been use carthage over a year without problem now i'm trying to add Mapbox to a new project and sent this error:

```
$ carthage update
Parse error: unexpected trailing characters in line: binary "https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/Mapbox-iOS-SDK.json" ~> 3.4
```

My Cartfile looks like this:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.0
binary "https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/Mapbox-iOS-SDK.json" ~> 3.5
```

Mapbox reference

[Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your version of Carthage.

Make sure you are on the latest version 0.20.1.  Trying out your cartfile, I had the same problem as you on an older version of Carthage.  I updated to the latest, and then it worked fine.

Comment: thanks, i only download the last build https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases